# Busca binária recursiva por string em C

Tags: c, algoritmo, algoritmo-de-busca, recursão, busca-binária

O enunciado do exercício pede-me que procure uma string num array ordenado de strings, usando a procura binária(comparar a string com o elemento a meio do array e depois comparar a string com um elemento à esquerda ou à direita). Também pede para fazer um código de forma recursiva e outro de forma iterativa. Então o código:

```
int procuraBinRec( char *p, char *ps[], int N, int offset ) 
{
    if( N < 1 ) return 0;
    int xN = N / 2;
    int x = strcmp( p,ps[ xN ] );
    if( x == 0 ) return offset + xN + 1;
    char* ps1[ xN ];

    for( int i = 0; i < xN; i++ ) 
    {
        ps1[ i ] = malloc( MAX_LINE + 1 );
        strcpy( ps1[ i ], ps[ i ] );
    }

    char* ps2[N - xN];

    for( int i = 0; i < N - xN - 1; i++ ) {
        ps2[ i ] = malloc( MAX_LINE + 1 );
        strcpy( ps2[ i ], ps[ i + xN + 1 ] );
    }
    if( x < 0 ) return procuraBinRec( p, ps1, xN, offset );
    else return procuraBinRec( p, ps2, N - xN - 1, offset + xN + 1 );
}
```

Encontrei esta resolução do exercício mas não consigo entender:

- O que é o `offset`.
- O que os ciclos `for` fazem.
- O `MAX_LINE` já está definido anteriormente.

Answer (score 3):

Esta função de busca binária recursiva tem vários problemas e algumas atipicidades.

A função cria desnecessariamente dois subvetores `ps1 e ps2` em cada execução, utilizando os loops `for` para copiar os dados do vetor original para estes subvetores (o que responde sua primeira pergunta). Estes subvetores foram criados para serem repassados nas chamadas recursivas, mas isto é desnecessário, uma vez que pode-se continuar buscando no vetor original. Também há um grande vazamento de memória, uma vez que este monte de vetores criados a cada chamada recursiva nunca é desalocado. Por fim, devemos eliminar os loops `for` e usar o próprio vetor original.

Geralmente em uma busca binária por `p`, tenta-se descobrir `j` tal que `v[j-1] < p <= v[j]`. Ou seja, mesmo não achando o índice do valor exato, se acha o índice do valor maior mais próximo. No caso da sua função, a intenção é diferente, pois retorna-se `0` quando não se encontra `p`.

Os índices de vetores em C vão de `0..N-1`, porém na sua função o valor retornado não é a posição do vetor na liguagem C, mas sim a posição no vetor com índices de `1..N`.

A cada chamada recursiva a função atuará em um subvetor, na metade inferior ou na metade superior da posição `N/2`. Quando se atua no subvetor na metade superior, precisa-se saber qual a posição que aquele subvetor começava no vetor original. Isto é o *offset*, ou seja, o *deslocamento* do subvetor a ser processado (o que responde a sua segunda pergunta).

Espero ter esclarecido suas dúvidas. Sugiro então uma versão otimizada e bastante comentada da função:

```
/* --- Função de busca binária ---
Parâmetros:
    p      -> elemento buscado
    ps     -> subvetor ordenado de busca
    N      -> quantidade de elementos no subvetor
    offset -> deslocamento do subvetor no vetor original
Retorno:
    se elemento não encontrado -> 0
    se elemento encontrado     -> índice no vetor entre 1..N */

int procuraBinRec(char *p, char *ps[], int N, int offset)
{
    // retorna 0 se tamanho do vetor é zero elementos (elemento p não encontrado)
    if(N < 1) return 0;

    // índice para divisão binária do vetor
    int xN = N / 2;

    // 0 se p == ps[xN], negativo se p < ps[xN], positivo se p > ps[xN]
    int x = strcmp(p, ps[xN]);

    // se p é exatamente o elemento do meio (p == ps[xN]), então retorna:
    // = o deslocamento do subvetor dentro do vetor original (offset)
    // + intervalo até o meio do subvetor (xN) +
    // + 1 porque se quer que os índices na resposta sejam de 1 a N
    if(x == 0) return offset + xN + 1;

    // se p < ps[xN] processa subvetor da metade inferior
    else if( x < 0 ) return procuraBinRec(p, ps, xN, offset);

    // se p > ps[xN] processa subvetor da metade superior
    else return procuraBinRec(p, ps + xN + 1, N - xN - 1, offset + xN + 1);
}
```

O desempenho das duas funções, se comparado, apresentará uma grande diferença no tempo de execução e no consumo de memória. Podemos fazer alguns teste simples para verificar esta afirmação.

Durante todos os testes utilizei os seguintes parâmetros:

- `MAX_LINE` = 80 caracteres
- `N` = 50.000.000 elementos
- `p` = a primeira string do vetor (péssimo caso)

Utilizei um código similar ao esboçado abaixo para testar o tempo de execução das funções:

```
#include <time.h>
...
clock_t t;
t = clock();
int x = procuraBinRec(p, ps, N, 0);
t = clock() - t;
printf("tempo = %.5lf s\n", ((double) t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

No meu computador, sem ocorrer swap, compilando com o `gcc -O0`, obtive os seguintes resultados:

```
Função da pergunta = 5.76911 s
Função da resposta = 0.00011 s
```

A diferença de consumo de memória entre as duas funções também foi grande. Fazendo as medições usando o programa `time`:

```
$ command time -f MaxRSS=%M ./bb
```

Obtive os resultados:

```
Função da pergunta: MaxRSS = 9.962 MB
Função da resposta: MaxRSS =   197 MB
```

Outra forma que utilizei para medir o consumo de memória foi com o programa `valgrind`. No caso, usei o `massif-visualizer` para gerar os gráficos a seguir:

```
valgrind --tool=massif ./bb
massif-visualizer massif.out.pid
```

[image: Função da Pergunta]

[image: Função da Resposta]

Comment: resposta muito boa! código muito bom!

Comment: Obrigado @zentrunix, adicionei ao final da resposta uma parte sobre comparação de desempenho das funções.